# Linq Update vs SQL Update performance

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008

Let say I got a `500 - 1,000` data in my table.

**LINQ**

```
(from a in db.Person 
     select a).ToList().ForEach(x => x.PersonName = "Juan");
db.SaveChanges();
```

**SQL**

```
UPDATE dbo.Person
SET PersonName = Juan;
```

Which query is much better performance in terms of speed when updating a record?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the raw update will be faster.  `ToList()` materialises the data set (so it gets read).  The update may or may not track changes in your entity but by default will.  Then it sends it all back again.

The update just operates at the database.

Without the `ToList()` it might be closer.